# Defining an Objects attributes based on the fields of a table

Tags: python, object

I have a class called Variant. 
At the moment this class has about 10 attributes like: name, position, genes, impact, father, mother, child, disease, reference, and alternative.

I don't suppose it really matters what these mean, but now the Variants that I am modelling with this class are coming with a lot of extra information, up to 30 different attributes, and it seems that to specifically mention every one in my constructor wouldn't be very "pythonic", in addition to error prone.

The Variants come in the form of a table with the attributes as column names. Is there a way to dynamically define the various attributes found in the table?

Comment: A table in a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a small factory function that creates a `Variant` object, reads the table, sets all the attributes from the table on it (using the built-in [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)) and returns the object.

Something like this (assuming you have the row information in a dict-like object with a key and an associated value):

```
def variant_from_table(row):
    variant = Variant()
    for key, value in row:
        setattr(variant, key, value)
    return variant
```